# chef locale resource does not apply properties

Tags: chef-infra

i am using chef version 16.9.20 and utilizing the [locale resource](https://docs.chef.io/resources/locale/) as follows

```rb
locale 'set system locale' do
  lang 'en_US.UTF-8'
end
```

i see that it is executed on chef-client run

```sh
* locale[set system locale]
```

the node is running ubuntu 20.04

```sh
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

when i log into the node and look at the locale, i see that it was not configured.

```sh
$ locale
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

$ cat /etc/default/locale
LANG=C.UTF-8

$ cat /etc/locale.conf
LANG=en_US.utf8
```

what is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The [locale](https://docs.chef.io/resources/locale/) resource seems to be updating the locale *partially*. Even the documentation is not clear on what aspects are updated.

**What is getting updated**

Config file `/etc/locale.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/locale.conf
LANG=en_US.utf8
```

`localectl`:

```
$ localectl status
  System Locale: LANG=en_US.utf8
  ..
```

**What is *not* getting updated**

The default locale `/etc/default/locale`:

This file is updated by the `update-locale` command:

```
$ sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.utf8
$ cat /etc/default/locale
LANG=en_US.utf8
```

`locale` command (terminal): The value of `LANG` in this command is directly linked to the `$LANG` environment variable.

```
$ echo $LANG
C.UTF-8
$ export LANG=en_US.utf8
$ locale
LANG=en_US.utf8
```

**What can we do**

Ubuntu documentation on setting locales: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale

Use the [execute](https://docs.chef.io/resources/execute/) resource to update the `/etc/default/locale` file using `update-locale` command

```rb
execute 'update-locale' do
  command 'update-locale LANG=en_US.utf8'
end
```

To set the `$LANG` environment variable (permanently) for the terminal there are [different ways](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) such as updating `/etc/environment`.

**Update:**

As per resource documentation, this resource is for setting **system's locale** on "Debian and Windows systems":

> Use the **locale** resource to set the system’s locale on Debian and Windows systems. Windows support was added in Chef Infra Client 16.0

Comment: the locale resource has no value then (at least for linux)

Comment: As per the documentation it is for **Debian and Windows systems** (and not for all Linux anyway).. And also mentioned is **system's locale**, so may be it as per design.  It may be worth reporting a feature request on [Github](https://github.com/chef/chef)..